# Drupal 7: How to load js and css files on different pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

What is the best way to load a js and css file on certain pages (not on every single page like happens when using the .info file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pages contain a form, you can use something similar to the following code:

```
$form['#attached']['css'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.css',
);

$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'ajax_example') . '/ajax_example.js',
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Drupal provides two functions: [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) and [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

You can use these at any point in your code to add a CSS or JS file to the page load.

Comment: For whatever reason this never works for me.  I added it in the page--node-type.tpl.php file.  Can it not go in there?

Comment: It won't work in a template file. Needs to be in a module file.